# Panda's boxplot but not showing the box

Tags: python, pandas, ipython, seaborn

Is there some way to use boxplots but only show the points?

I have this:

```
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data2 = pd.DataFrame(dict(site85_574C=[10,20,30,40, 50], site41_366A=[5,15, 25, 35, 45]),  columns=["site85_574C", "site41_366A"])
data2.boxplot(widths=0.05)
plt.scatter(np.repeat(np.arange(data2.shape[1])+1, data2.shape[0]), data2.values.ravel(), marker='+', alpha=1.0)
```

but I only want to see the points in the verticle lines, not the box and whiskers

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
data2.boxplot(widths=0.05,  showbox=False, whiskerprops={'lw': 0})
```

Note, `showbox` and `whiskerprops` are the `kwds` of boxplot, which are in turn passed to `matplotlib.boxplot`.

Reference

http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.boxplot.html

http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html

Comment: I get a "boxplot() got an unexpected keyword argument 'whiskerprops'" putting that in.   I see the kwds item you reference in the pandas doc.  It doesn't seem to let me pass these through though.  Any ideas?

Comment: Weird. Maybe your matplotlib is outdated?

Comment: yep.. that was it..  an update and things are working!  THANKS!